# How to run an ActiveX component method without blocking the possessing control?

Tags: c++, activex

```
BSTR CCtrl::mosMsgFromHost(BSTR mosMsg)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    AfxMessageBox(mosMsg);
    mainDialog.GetWebView()->PostWebMessageAsString(mosMsg);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
    cv.wait(ul);
    AfxMessageBox(mainDialog.receivedMessage);
    return mainDialog.receivedMessage.AllocSysString();
}
```

I have laid out a WebView2 component in ActiveX Control. When its following method is called, it forwards the message it gets to WebView2 to be processed and returned by means of an event that notifies cv, which is the condition variable so that it continues to the rest below *cv.wait(ul)*.

Everything is fine and working like a charm but the issue here is blocking the entire ActiveX control while it is waiting. I cannot tweak at the client side that uses the ActiveX control we're designing, so I cannot make it Asynchronous ActiveX control. So is there any recommendation to solve this issue?

Comment: Forcing async code to execute synchronously invariably leads to disappointment.  You'll have to change the return type of this function to *void* and doctor whatever code that now signals the cv to make a callback to the code that now handles the function return value.  How practical (and dangerous) that might be is impossible to guess from the itty-bitty code we can see.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in still, you can use the following workaround that allows us to achieve what we want to do:

```
while (some_condition)
{
    MSG msg;
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

If your some_condition becomes false through an event, however, it will cease the loop. That way, you don't have to freeze the whole application that is the owner of the thread we're currently operating on. It can be deemed as tricky, it serves our purpose well.

Answer (score 0):

If the control is apartment threaded I doubt you are going to make this work. Calls to apartment objects either need to be made on the apartment thread (which generally needs to be the main application thread) or use a proxy (even if from within the same process) that transfers the call to the apartment thread.

I do not know whether your object is in fact apartment threaded or not, although that is extremely common for ActiveX UI controls.

Are you sure the object doesn't offer a connection point that could be used instead?